# Clicking a tag in jobs causing console errors

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

This seems to be happening across the jobs portion of so.
Here's the error:

[image]

I believe I got it when clicking a tag name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up Jon. A dev feature was partially enabled in prod. Switched off now, which eliminates the JS error.